# incompatible types error is displayed after upgrading Spring to 5.3.20

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

all,
I have a maven java project with junits:
for example:

```
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
    import com.jayway.jsonassert.impl.matcher.IsCollectionWithSize;      
 @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        getMockMvc().perform(put("/bla")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .content("{\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "\"eventTypes\": [\"BLA\"]\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "}"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.eventTypes", IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(1)));
    }
```

the line that run the check:
jsonPath("$.eventTypes", IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(1)

the jsonPath is part of Spring libary verion 4.3.30
and the IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize is taken form com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path-assert verion 2.4

everything worked ok until I upgraded the Spring to 5.3.20
The error is:

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,capture#79 of ? super java.util.Collection<? extends E>,E
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; org.hamcrest.Matcher<capture#80 of ? super java.util.Collection<? extends E>> cannot be converted to org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.lang.Object>)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone had such a problem? And can offer a solution?

Comment: aren't you missing a closing parenthesis ) after "$.eventTypes" ?
in the last line i see 3 open parenthesis ( and only 2 closing.

Comment: no, this code worked before I upgraded the Spring

Comment: not the code in the original question, since it doesn't compile. you now edited the code and corrected the parentheses. if the code is not accurate, we can't help you.
the problem remains, that Jayway cannot pinpoint the type of collection you are trying to assert its size. what happens when you try IsCollectionWithSize<?>.hasSize(1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I fixed it by changing one of the imports.
instead of this:

```
import com.jayway.jsonassert.impl.matcher.IsCollectionWithSize;
```

I used this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
```

and change the code from this:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$.eventTypes", IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(1)));
```

to this:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$.eventTypes", hasSize(1)))
```